# How can I use multiple buttons for AJAX Calls?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

```
<div class="form-group">
          <div >
              <a href="/addcourse">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ">add course</button>
        </a>
    <div class="center">
      
      <h1>manage courses</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 500px">
    <form class="form-horizontal" style="width: 50%;">
    
     
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="faculty" class="col-sm-2 control-label" ></label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button index=0 id='facultyDropdown' class="btn">Faculties</button>
              <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  {{#facultyId}}
                     <li><a index="{{id}}">{{faculty}}</a></li>
                  {{/facultyId}}              
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
              <input id="submit" name="submit" type="bottom" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">

               <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col1" >corse code</th>
            <th scope="col1" >course name</th>
            <th scope="col2">credit hourse</th>
           
            <th scope="col5"></th>
            <th scope="col6"></th>
          </tr >
          <tbody id="myTable"></tbody>
        </thead>
      </table>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
    </div>
```

This HTML page has 2 main buttons and I generated two more buttons in every table row. The two buttons in the row don't work with ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function buildTable(data){
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = "";
    
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].code}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].course}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].id}</td>
              <td><button id=${data[i].id} name="update" type="button" value="${data[i].id}"  class="update" >update</button></td>
              <td><button id=${data[i].id} name="update" type="button" value="${data[i].id}"  class="delete" >delete</button></td>
                      </tr>`
          
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    const index = $(this).attr('index');
    $("#facultyDropdown").attr('index', index);
    $("#facultyDropdown").text($(this).text());
  });
 
  $("#submit").click(function() {

    console.log('alaa');
    
    const facultyId = $("#facultyDropdown").attr('index');

   
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: `/api/v1/faculties/`+`${facultyId}`,
      
      success:function(res){
        courses= res
      
        buildTable(courses)
        console.log('courses')
        
      }    
    });
  });  

 $(".delete").click(function() {
 
    const corseid = $(this).attr("id");
   
   console.log(corseid);

   
    $.ajax({
      type: "delete",
      url: `/api/v1/courses/`+`${corseid}`,
      
      success:function(res){
       alert(`course deleted ${res}`)
        
      }    
    });

  
  
  });  


  $(".update").click(function() {
 
    const corseid = $(this).attr("id");
   
   console.log(corseid);

   
    $.ajax({
      type: "put",
      url: `/api/v1/courses/`+`${corseid}`,
      
      success:function(res){
       alert(`course deleted ${res}`)
        
      }    
    });

  
  
  });  
      
});
```

This is the ajax code above, I don't understand that the droplist and the add course button and submit button is working only the update and delete buttons are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you create your event handler, the elements don't exist (since they only exist after clicking `submit`).

You need to use event delegation, there are a few ways of doing that, this is probably the easiest:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ".delete", function (event) {
// your delete code
});
```